Hash mismatch error for unknown package while building Docker image
As I am trying to build docker image, I am keep getting error during pip installation:
2775.3 ERROR: THESE PACKAGES DO NOT MATCH THE HASHES FROM THE REQUIREMENTS FILE. If you have updated the package versions, please update the hashes. Otherwise, examine the package contents carefully; someone may have tampered with them.  
2775.3     unknown package:
2775.3         Expected sha256 f083fc24912aa410be21fa16d157fed2055dab1cc4b6934a0e03cba69eb242b9
2775.3              Got        3efa059ccefefd80228c849800b5f4d1b8dcf25aac45213bf937fe75fe19a554
2775.3
-

Dockerfile:12
-

10 |  
11 |     # Install the specified packages
12 | >>> RUN pip install -r requirements.txt --no-cache-dir
13 |

I tried googling this hash mismatch error for a while, but all the cases I encountered at least had a package name that has the error.
Below is my current Dockerfile:
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.12

# Set pip configurations for better stability
ENV PIP_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT=500 \
    PIP_DISABLE_PIP_VERSION_CHECK=1 \
    PIP_NO_CACHE_DIR=1

# Copy requirements.txt
COPY requirements.txt ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}

# Install the specified packages
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt --no-cache-dir

# For local testing.
EXPOSE 8000

# Set IS_USING_IMAGE_RUNTIME Environment Variable
ENV IS_USING_IMAGE_RUNTIME=True

# Copy all files in ./src
COPY src/* ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}
COPY src/rag_app ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}/rag_app
COPY src/data/vectorstore ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}/data/vectorstore

And this is my requirements.txt file:
fastapi==0.115.4
langchain==0.3.7
langchain_community==0.3.5
langchain_core==0.3.15
langchain_huggingface==0.1.2
mangum==0.19.0
pydantic==2.9.2
uvicorn==0.32.0

My laptop is Windows btw
What I tried:
adding/not adding --no-cache-dir parameter
adding/not adding --verbose parameter to investigate
add update pip before the pip install
adding/not adding --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org
None of the above worked and I got the same error.
I am not using any VPN and I am still stuck with this issue.
Does anyone know why this is happening and how I should resolve this error?
